# Same functionality sometimes logs me out (ReturnUrl)

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a .NET Core Web application with pretty limited functionality. I have a very strange error which occurs **occasionally**.

I'm using Microsoft Identity for authorization. Sometimes when I, or others, are using the web application we can login without problems but when you try to access a functionality you get instantly logged out and sent to the Login screen with a ReturnUrl.
And sometimes, when you use the exactly same functionality, doing the exact same thing, it works without problems. There's no timeout involved, there's no-one publishing any new release of the web application or doing anything else on the web server or IIS.

Has anyone ever experienced this and/or have any idea why this could happen?

Comment: Without code example, it's really tough to explain what is the exact problem. It may happen for Login session timeout, authorization of the controller, or something other than these. So check these issue & check if they happen again.

Comment: I understand that. It's not a session logout timeout, the problem occurs seconds after that you have logged in. There is authorization on the controller but the same code is being executed, by the same user, in the same way. Sometimes you get logged out, sometimes not.

I guess I was hoping that someone had experienced the same thing.

Comment: IF it happens it usually happens the first time I access the web application. If I log in again, it then works. But again, it's not that the problem occurs every time, just occasionally and I haven't been able to find any logic explanation.

Comment: Hey @Damol I have exactly the same problem. If you've found the answer can you please add it here?